# switching between multiple images

Tags: javascript, onclick, switch-statement

I've got this in my js:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:first-child').click(function(){
        $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:first-child').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:nth-child(2)').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
        $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:nth-child(2)').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:nth-child(3)').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

...And so on.

I've got multiple images which I want to be able to switch through with a click function. But how i'm writing it down now is a lot of code. Is there a way of putting this into 1 function?

Comment: Any chance of some html to see your basic structure? As for your functions, I believe you could use `$(this).fadeOut('slow'); $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');` instead of `$('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:first-child').fadeOut('slow'); $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100:nth-child(2)').fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the visible image and pass that as a parameter to the function. Than you can easily calculate which images should fade in and out.

Can you make a fiddle with something that works? I can edit the fiddle and show you how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot, but without seeing your html structure I can't test it.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.slide:nth-child(11) .layout-100').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
      if ($(this).next().length)
        $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
      else
        $(this).parent().children().first().fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Well this works! Only problem, I would like if when the last item is reached and you click again, you return to the first item. Is that possible?

Comment: @Luc you can try my updated answer. I'm not 100% sure the `.first()` function is right so it may need changing, let me know. And don't forget to accept/up-vote if it does work :)